# how to use ajax for validation and submission of form data, if there are more than five forms are present with different ID

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, web

I make a webpage that consist 6 forms with different ID (contatcForm, emailForm, inquiryForm, CompForm & otherForm). All forms has 4 fields (name, email, subject & message).
Now the problem is : I'm unable to find the the appropriate way to use ajax for validation and submission of specific form only.

My current script is :

/ $('html').on is used because form page is loaded via ajax/

```
  $('html').on ('click','.sendit', function (){
     Var a = $(this).parent ('form').attr ('id');
     a.submit (submit);
   });


 function submit (){
  Var form = $(this);
  If (! $(.name).val () || ! $(.email).val () || ! $(.subject).val () || ! $(.message).val ()){
   $('.incomp').show ();
   } else {
     $('.sending').show ();
   $.ajax ({
      url: form.attr ('action') + "?ajax=true",
      type: form.attr ('method'),
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: finished
  });
  }
  return false;
  }
  Function finished (response){
    response = $.trim (response);
     $('.sending').show ();
    If (response == "success"){
      $('.success').show ();
    } else {
     $('.error').show ();
    }
   }
```

This script will submit form data very well but, the disadvantage of using this is : '.show ();' executed on all form.

HTML CODE :

```
                   <ul><li>Contact</li>
            <form id="contactForm" action="processForm.php" method="post">
            <span class="sending"><p>Sending your message. Please wait...</p></span>
            <span class="success"><p>Thanks for sending your message! We'll get back to you shortly.</p></span>
            <span class="error"><p>There was a problem sending your message. Please try again.</p></span>
            <span class="incomp"><p>Please complete all the fields in the form before sending.</p></span>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" />
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" />
            <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" class="sendit" name="sendMessage" value="Send Email" />
        </form></li>
           <li>Inquiry</li>
            <form id="inquiryForm" action="processForm.php" method="post">
            <span class="sending"><p>Sending your message. Please wait...</p></span>
            <span class="success"><p>Thanks for sending your message! We'll get back to you shortly.</p></span>
            <span class="error"><p>There was a problem sending your message. Please try again.</p></span>
            <span class="incomp"><p>Please complete all the fields in the form before sending.</p></span>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" />
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" />
            <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" class="sendit" name="sendMessage" value="Send Email" />
        </form>
               </ul>
```

other forms are same, but formID is different according to the title of form (#complaintForm, #otherForm)

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Can you show us the HTML code?

Comment: @jepser: question is updated with the HTML CODE. Thanks

Comment: you should look at `jQuery.form` js

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)
If u have five forms with five different Ids. Assign same class to all the forms say `.forms`

Then call ajax function as

```
$('.forms').ajaxForm(function(response){
   //Do whatever you want with response here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript code add the context of the div you want to show, just like this:

```
$('.incomp', form).show();
```

As you have that `form = $(this)`;

Or:

```
form.find('.incomp').show();
```

Hope it helps!